# How to draw a text HORIZONTALLY on top of Pie Chart, currently drawText() is drawing the text parallel to the chart

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want my text to be aligned horizontal to the chart using drawText from canvas
Currently I'm only able to draw the text parallel to the pie chart as below

This is what I have which draw the text parallel to the chart in slant position

```
                        drawText( // TEXT on top of the chart
                            "${pieChartInput.description}",
                            circleCenter.x,
                            circleCenter.y + radius * 1.2f * factor,
                            Paint().apply {
                                textSize = 12.sp.toPx()
                                textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
                                color = gray.toArgb()
                                isFakeBoldText = true
                            }
                        )
```